# Graphing a Hyperbolic Paraboloid in PSTricks

Tags: xetex, luatex, pstricks, graphs

I saw the graph of the following hyperbolic paraboloid [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PSTricks-Hyperboloid.png).

[image]

I believe this one is done via **PSTricks**. I can only do the axes as seen in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add}
\usepackage[width=8.29in, height=11.64in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-5)(5,6.5)
\pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt,IIIDxTicksPlane=xz, IIIDyTicksPlane=yz,spotX=180,xMin=-4,xMax=5,yMin=-2.25,yMax=4,zMin=-5,zMax=5,nameX=$x$, nameY=$y$, nameZ=$z$, labels=none] 
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

May I know how to graph this one using PSTricks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
    
\psset{viewpoint=50 40 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-8)(7,8)
\psSurface[ngrid=.25 .25,incolor=yellow,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,axesboxed,algebraic,hue=0 1](-4,-4)(4,4){ ((y^2)-(x^2))/4 }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same with `pst-3plot`  which doesn't know hidden surfaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-4)(6,5)
\psset{Beta=15,Alpha=60}
\psplotThreeD[plotstyle=line,drawStyle=xLines,algebraic=true,
    yPlotpoints=50,xPlotpoints=50,linewidth=1pt](-4,4)(-4,4){ ((y^2)-(x^2))/4 }
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-1,xMax=5,yMin=-1,yMax=5,zMin=-1,zMax=5]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to graph it using `pst-3dplot`?

Comment: sure, but it does not know hidden surfaces ... see edit

Comment: Thank you. One more question: Is it possible to cut some portions of the graph by restricting the z-values in the plot? For example, I only want the graph with z-values from -4 to 4.

Comment: That graph has z values from -4 to 4

Comment: Sorry. I mean if for z-values from -3 to 3, for instance.

Comment: `...(-3.46,3.46)(-3.46,3.46){ ((y^2)-(x^2))/4 }`. for `-3<z<3` we get `x|y = sqrt(12)`

Comment: Is it possible to have all xand y values on [-4,4] and the z-values on [-3,3]? Like literally cutting the paraboloid above and below by the planes z=3 and z=-3? I am thinking that this could be done via `implicit equation` to also indicate bounds for z. Thank you so much. ^^

Comment: there is no special option. You have to clip the image and convert the 3d data into xy by yourself.

Comment: For the surface graphed using `pst-solides3d`, is it possible to restrict the graph for z-values from 0 to 3?

Comment: the same as in your other question: `y dup mul x dup mul sub 4 div  dup 3 gt { pop 3 } if`  Only possible without the `algebraic` mode